# Checking if remote git tag has changed

Tags: git

I have a local git repo, with a worktree synced to a particular tag.  I want to see if the origin repo has changed that tag, as efficiently as possible, and if so create a new worktree.

I was using `git rev-list -n1 tagname` to see the hash of my local tag and `git ls-remote -q origin refs/tags/tagname^{}` to see the remote's tag.

This works for all the cases I have tested except now I find that in some cases the `^{}` causes it to return empty.  The remote has the tag, but not the `^{}` form of it.

e.g.

```
$ git ls-remote --tags
From https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync
8bb6ccf948dbdfdb8a2d88d13db96e272e3573b8    refs/tags/v2.0.0
15ba74321c4ce41aa935271105e999011afc2d01    refs/tags/v2.0.1
7984f521cf97a8aeffffa5da490dfb5410c6273b    refs/tags/v2.0.2

$ git ls-remote -q origin refs/tags/v2.0.0^{}
```

What am I messing up?  How can I handle both cases that have ^{} and need to be dereferenced as well as cases that do not?

There has to be a simpler answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^{}` is really a bit of [gitrevisions syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  It tells Git to *peel* a tag: to find the object to which the (presumably annotated) tag points, rather than finding the annotated tag itself.

> I was using `git rev-list -n1 tagname` to see the hash of my local tag ...

This is the real source of the problem: `git rev-list` lists *commits*, but tag references might not point to commits.  When the tag reference points to an annotated tag, you should probably obtain the hash ID of the annotated tag object.  To do that, use `git rev-parse` instead of `git rev-list`:

```
$ git rev-parse v2.19.1
0d3c37ddaccbb48809fdd3810ebb3f2bc961973c
$ git rev-parse v2.19.1^{}
cae598d9980661a978e2df4fb338518f7bf09572
$ git rev-list -n1 v2.19.1
cae598d9980661a978e2df4fb338518f7bf09572
```

(here `v2.19.1` is an annotated tag in the Git repository for Git).  Note how the tag's annotated tag leads to the commit, so that `git rev-parse` with the peel option and `git rev-list` both found the same commit.<sup>1</sup>

When using `git ls-remote`, if the remote's tag is annotated, the remote delivers both the tag's object hash *and*, with the `^{}` suffix, the hash ID of the object to which the annotated tag resolves.<sup>2</sup>  If the remote's tag is *not* annotated, `git ls-remote` delivers the hash ID of the object to which that tag points.  (The tag points there directly rather than through an annotated tag object.)

Tags should never change—e.g., should never go from annotated to un-annotated or vice versa, as well as never changing underlying objects—but if the tag ever *does* change, the hash ID will change, even if the underlying tagged object hash ID is the same.  But in such a case you probably want to update your local tag anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup>If the tag points to some other object type—a tree or blob—the `git rev-list` would do nothing, while the `git rev-parse` will succeed; one can use `^{commit}` to get `git rev-parse` to fail:

```
$ git rev-list -n1 xxx
$ git rev-parse xxx
596ad6ec669abd0c6ad6034cd3b219fb6ea3ab1d
$ git cat-file -p xxx
object b22571e0489ee9a664885594316a7ccfc9186360
type blob
[snip]
$ git rev-parse xxx^{}
b22571e0489ee9a664885594316a7ccfc9186360
$ git rev-parse xxx^{commit}
error: xxx^{commit}: expected commit type, but the object dereferences to blob type
xxx^{commit}
error: xxx^{commit}: expected commit type, but the object dereferences to blob type
fatal: ambiguous argument 'xxx^{commit}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

<sup>2</sup>Note that if an annotated tag object points to another annotated tag object, or to a chain of annotated tag objects, the `^{}` resolving process still finds the final object, whatever that is.  So it's better to talk about the "resolved object" or the "peeled value" or whatever phrase you like to describe the process of finding a non-tag object.

(Peeling a non-annotated tag, or any other valid hash ID, is a no-op, but is allowed.  You can add as many `^{}` suffixes as you like, though only the first one does anything, and even then, only if the object is an annotated tag.)

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I have some followup questions that are not clear to me.

Comment: You suggest using rev-parse to get the annotated tag, but later you said it's better to talk about the peeled value.  Isn't rev-list the peeled value?

I'm fixing up a tool that syncs a local view of a remote git repo and trying to handle as many oddball cases as possible as correctly as possible.  I assumed that resolving down to commit hashes was the most "peeled" I could get?

The goal was to say, given a hash, branch name, or tag name, check what that resolves to locally, check what it resolves to upstream, and if not equal, sync and make a new worktree from upstream.

Comment: `git rev-list` only works for commits (which, admittedly, is most tags). If you want the peeled value, you can use that, or—for reliability in the face of non-commit tags—the `^{}` or `^{commit}` syntax with `git rev-parse`. In any case, given the point of your tool, you would want the *un-peeled* tag in case someone replaces an annotated tag with a signed annotated tag, pointing to the same object, but using a GPG signature this time.

Comment: In any case, read that "talk about" sentence again (or maybe I should rephrase it): I'm saying that if you *mean* "the object to which the tag points after peeling as many times as necessary", use the "peel" verb; if you *mean* "the tag itself", there's no single verb to clarify this.

Comment: I really wanted to reference the commit to which the tag points.  When I `ls-remote` a tag that is not annotated, and I use the peel syntax, it returns nothing.  That's what I was struggling with.  Man page makes it sound like it is just syntax that should be a no-op for non-annotated tags, but it just doesn't work.  ANYWAY, I will switch to rev-parse since it seems to cause no harm to reference the tag itself and works for both annotated an non.  THANKS!!